# How can I make the minipages align to the top?

Tags: tables, minipage

I have this structure, on the left side two tables and on the right side one table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \center
    \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Heading}\\
            \hline
            One & Two & Three\\
            \hline
            One & Two & Three\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}\\
    
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Heading}\\
            \hline
            One & Two & Three\\
            \hline
            One & Two & Three\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Heading}\\
            \hline
            One & Two & Three\\
            \hline
            One & Two & Three\\
            \hline
            One & Two & Three\\
            \hline
            One & Two & Three\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}\\
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The generated PDF looks like so:
[image]

As you can see the tables on the left side is shifted a little bit towards the bottom. How can I prevent that?

Comment: simply use `[t]` also in `tabular`s.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Comment: The [t] option in minipage means align the first baseline, so it aligned the centers of the top two tabulars (default to [c]).